# Invalid application descriptor: Version number must have a non-empty value

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.1">
    <id>samples.flex.HelloWorld</id>
    <version>1</version>
    <filename>HelloWorld</filename>
    <initialWindow>
        <content>HelloWorld.swf</content>
        <visible>true</visible>
        <systemChrome>none</systemChrome>
        <transparent>true</transparent>
        <width>400</width>
        <height>200</height>
    </initialWindow>
</application>
```

i use:

```
adl HelloWorld-app.xml
```

i get an error

```
Invalid application descriptor: Version number must have a non-empyy value
```

what I am doing wrong?

I am using flex 4.6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `<versionNumber>1</versionNumber>` instead of `<version>1</version>` in your XML descriptor file.